# Unable to free an integer array in a struct

Tags: c, memory-management

I have been trying to make tree which has exactly 9 children of which some are uninitialized, so practically it is a tree of variable number of children. The indices of the children which are initialized are put in an array which has the size of the number of children that the tree node is supposed to have. And while freeing the whole tree of its memory allocation, I wanted to free that array, too, but I have encountered a problem which is that for some reason there is an error when I try to do so. Here is the code snippet which is fully executable after compilation, though, if someone would be so nice to help debug it for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct moveNode
{
    int rating;
    // char player;
    int numPossibleMoves, *possibleMoves;
    struct moveNode **children;
};

struct moveNode *moveTreeHead;
struct moveNode *createHeadNode(void);
void initializeNode(struct moveNode *node, char *boardState);

int main()
{
    moveTreeHead = createHeadNode();

    printf("moveTreeHead->possibleMoves[1] %d\n", moveTreeHead->possibleMoves[1]);
    free(moveTreeHead->possibleMoves);
}

void initializeNode(struct moveNode *node, char *boardState)
{
    int i, possibleMovesCounter = -1;
    node->numPossibleMoves = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (boardState[i] != 'x' && boardState[i] != 'o')
        {
            node->numPossibleMoves++;
        }
    }

    if (node->numPossibleMoves != 0)
    {
        node->possibleMoves = (int *)malloc(sizeof *(node->possibleMoves));
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        {
            if (boardState[i] != 'x' && boardState[i] != 'o')
            {
                possibleMovesCounter++;
                node->possibleMoves[possibleMovesCounter] = i;
                node->children[i] = (struct moveNode *)malloc(sizeof *(node->children[i]));
                node->children[i]->numPossibleMoves = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        node->possibleMoves = NULL;
    }
}

struct moveNode *createHeadNode()
{
    struct moveNode *ret = (struct moveNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct moveNode));
    ret->children = (struct moveNode **)malloc(sizeof *(ret->children) * 9);
    initializeNode(ret, "012345678");
    return ret;
}
```

I get the following debugging error message:

```
warning: HEAP[helloworld.exe]:
warning: Heap block at 0000028AA9C23530 modified at 0000028AA9C23544 past requested size of 4

Thread 1 received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
0x00007ffa1046a773 in ntdll!RtlRegisterSecureMemoryCacheCallback () from C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
```

What exactly does that mean? All I am trying to do is to free an integer array which has been properly allocated with `malloc`. What is the problem here? And I even tested out that there is no problem with the array that has been created with `printf("moveTreeHead->possibleMoves[1] %d\n", moveTreeHead->possibleMoves[1])`.

Edit: Problem solved, thank you!! @UnholySheep

Comment: `node->possibleMoves = (int *)malloc(sizeof *(node->possibleMoves));` allocates memory for exactly one `int` yet you later potentially access as if it were a larger array

Comment: IMHO you'd be better off with `struct moveNode *children[9];` since you already know you want 9 of them. That will save some memory management.

Comment: @yano Yes, I will do that. Now, I don't need to do `malloc` for the array of pointers.

Answer (score 0):

`node->possibleMoves = (int *)malloc(sizeof *(node->possibleMoves));` allocates memory for exactly one `int` yet you later potentially access as if it were a larger array  [@UnholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74996091/unable-to-free-an-integer-array-in-a-struct#comment132345639_74996091)

---

Other:

Casts not needed in the various allocations.